# This is my query but there is a column I does not want to group by, but I want it to use in when condition

Tags: sql, case

Here I use sr.SourceTransactionType in case statement but I does not select it.
But code does not allow me to use sr.SourceTransactionType with out group by sr.SourceTransactionType
So please give me suggestions

```
BEGIN
    SELECT it.Description AS ItemType
        ,iv.ItemCode
        ,iv.Description AS ItemName
        ,un.Description AS Unit
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'OBL'
                THEN SUM(sr.Quantity)
            END AS 'OBLQTY'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'OBL'
                THEN SUM(sr.Quantity * sr.UnitRate)
            END AS 'OBLAMOUNT'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'GRND'
                THEN SUM(sr.Quantity)
            END AS 'GRNQTY'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'GRND'
                THEN SUM(sr.Quantity * sr.UnitRate)
            END AS 'GRNAMOUNT'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'RCPT'
                THEN SUM(sr.Quantity)
            END AS 'RCPTQTY'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'RCPT'
                THEN SUM(sr.Quantity * sr.UnitRate)
            END AS 'RCPTAMOUNT'
        ,SUM(sr.IssuedQuantity) AS IssuedQty
        ,SUM(sr.IssuedQuantity * sr.UnitRate) AS IssuedAmount
        ,SUM(sr.IssueReturnQuantity) AS IssRtnQty
        ,SUM(sr.IssueReturnQuantity * sr.UnitRate) AS IssRtnAmount
        ,SUM(sr.DispatchedQuantity) AS DispatchQty
        ,SUM(sr.DispatchedQuantity * sr.UnitRate) AS DispatchAmount
    FROM [dbo].[sms_StockRegister] sr
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[sms_ItemVersion] iv ON sr.ItemId = iv.ItemId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[cmn_ItemType] it ON iv.ItemTypeId = it.ItemTypeId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[cmn_Unit] un ON iv.UnitId = un.UnitId
    GROUP BY iv.Description,it.Description,iv.ItemCode
             ,ac4.AccountCodeGN4Code,un.Description
    ORDER BY iv.Description
END
```

Comment: What is the error message, if any?  Can you include sample data which helps to explain the problem you are having here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression in the `aggregate function` as follows:

**Replace**

```
CASE WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'OBL' THEN SUM(sr.Quantity) END AS 'OBLQTY'
```

**with**

```
SUM(CASE WHEN sr.SourceTransactionType = 'OBL' THEN sr.Quantity END) AS 'OBLQTY'
```

You need to change the same way in other aggregate functions in your query.

Comment: If it solved your issue then you can mark this question as accepted so that this question is marked as resolved.